# How to store PHP arrays in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I store php arrays in mysql and then filter them?

For example:

```
$array = array("a"=>13,"b"=>15,"c"=>17);

$mysql_val = json_encode($array);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO bla (`myfield`) VALUES('".$mysql_val."')"); 
             ^- i store data in this way
```

When I execute this query, how can I filter, sort, etc. it?
For example, how can I select rows where b is bigger than 10?

Comment: Why are you storing your data this way?

Comment: Because i need some dynamical field.

Comment: @TamásSzabó Then make another table called columns, with a column called `column_type` and go from there.

Comment: This is the *wrong* way to store data. You should be adding more rows to a table or having the columns to deal with the data. If the data can be any number of array elements, then use rows.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a document database like mongo db

Comment: You should alwawys use prepared statements (using PDO for example).

Answer (score 2):

First off you're using your database incorrectly, this is why you can't filter sort etc...

You should have a column for each `a, b, c`, then you could use `SELECT * FROM bla ORDER BY a DESC` or potentially better for you, have a table that maps keys => values instead.

By storing your data as a **string** MySQL **doesn't** have access to it so you cannot sort on it.

The correct (normalised) way to store this data if you don't know the key (field) name is like the below:

```
bla
id | name
-- | ----
2  | james

blaDecorator or blaColumns
id | blaId | field | value
1  | 2     | a     | 13
2  | 2     | b     | 15
3  | 2     | c     | 17
```

If you **must** keep your data like this (and I see no reason why) then you'll need to `SELECT * FROM bla` read it into PHP as an `Array` and do all your sorting with PHP

Here's a resource for learning about database normalization: http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/

Answer (score 2):

This is the very reason for database normalisation, specifically 1st normal form, avoiding repeating groups. By storing your data atomically (the data cannot be broken down into smaller pieces), you'll be able to perform operations on the data.

Answer (score 1):

No, JSON data is for MySQL just a piece of text, so it cannot process it apart from running usual text functions.

You'll have to read them from your database and text and convert into JSON on PHP level, then sort or filter in your application.

If this is critical for you consider using NoSQL database, many of them JSON based natively.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

This is a terrible way to store data in a database. Store the data as columns and use the database as a database.

But, if you must, then use PostgeSQL. See: http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2012/03/json_in_postgres.html

The latest version of PostgeSQL has functions to query data inside a json string and do joins on it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider using a document database like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), if you want to store your data as json. With it you will be able to search, filter etc. within your json data

Answer (score 0):

Do not store data like that! 
Make 3 fields and store the data in those fields.

Example:

```
$array = array("a"=>13,"b"=>15,"c"=>17);
$fields = array_keys($array);

mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO bla ( " . explode(',', $fields) . ") 
VALUES('" . explode(',' $array) . "')");
```

Comment: But this doesnt create the fields.

Answer (score 0):

While all of the responders question the use of the DB. There are actual use cases where this is appropriate. I am facing such an issue and this is my solution:

```
function prepareArrayToSave($array) {
    return (implode("", array_map("numberPad", $array)));
}

function numberPad($i) {
    return sprintf("%03d", $i);
}
```

Save in field `Decimal(64)`.

Limits are:

1. Each value in array can not be greater than 999;
2. Any array shall not have more than 21 values.